# Simplify a sql statement in transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to simplify the following query :

```
INSERT INTO TP.VA(IDB,IDP,IDVS,IDVB)
SELECT 
 @IDB,@IDP,IDVIS,IDVTP
FROM 
 TP.VP
WHERE 
 IDP = @IDP AND
 NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
              FROM TP.VA A
                   INNER JOIN TP.VP B 
                   ON A.IDP=B.IDP 
               WHERE 
                   A.IDB = @IDB 
                   AND A.IDP = @IDP 
                   AND A.IDVIS = IDVB 
                   AND A.IDVD=IDVTP )
```

I would like to understand if it is possible to simplify it especially after the NOT EXISTS. How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean by simplify?

Comment: Optimize ussually refers to improve query performance, while simplify refers to writing a shorter, easier to read query. Which one are you concerned about?

Comment: I want to simplify the code. A equivalent sql statement but more simple.

Comment: We can usually replace a `NOT EXISTS()` with an exclusion join, but the `NOT EXISTS()` almost always performs meaningfully better.

Comment: Is it intended that that `NOT EXISTS` isn't correlated? As the object in the outer `FROM` is also `TP.VP` then `= IDVB` and `=IDVTP` are going to be parsed as `= B.IDVB` and `=B.IDVTP` so those clauses might as well be in the `ON`.

Comment: I've added the SQL Server tag, as that's the main RDBMS that uses T-SQL. If, however, you are using Azure SQL Database, Azure Synapse, Sybase, or even something else that uses T-SQL, please correct the tag.

Comment: `AND A.IDVIS = IDVB ` Do NOT develop this bad habit. Always qualify every column reference with the appropriate alias.

Comment: I very much doubt this query is working as intended anyway, because the subquery is not correlated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could 'simplify' the query by removing the join - it isn't needed.

```
INSERT INTO TP.VA(IDB,IDP,IDVS,IDVB)
SELECT 
 @IDB,@IDP,IDVIS,IDVTP
FROM 
 TP.VP    B
WHERE 
 IDP = @IDP AND
 NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
              FROM TP.VA A
               WHERE 
                   A.IDB = @IDB 
                   AND A.IDP = B.IDP
                   AND A.IDVIS = B.IDVB 
                   AND A.IDVD = B.IDVTP )
```